# Filter analytics goal report by device

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

Is it possible to share an analytics goal and then filter by device when viewing the report?

We are programmatically registering a goal from the website (through webapi) and it's working fine. We now want to allow a mobile app to use the same webapi to register the same user action, hence the same goal. Will we be able to separate/filter by channel when reporting so we to distinguish them?

Comment: I want to say yes. I know that analytics does facet by channel/device. But I haven't tested this completely. Though I have stories in my current project backlog doing just this.. so I'll let you know once I get to them. marking this as a favorite question to remind me.

Comment: I think this is possible but be sure to buy the device detection services and enable them, which is add on and can be purchased from the sitecore app center

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, you can upvote it and accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't specified version of Sitecore that you use, I will show you how to do this in Sitecore 9 and XConnect. I believe something similar can be done also for Sitecore 8 with XDB as channels are in Sitecore for quite some time now. In Sitecore 7.x these were called [traffic types](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/marketing_operations/channels/map_traffic_types_to_channels).

More information about channels can be found here:
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/marketing_operations/channels/channels

1.
Go to Marketing Control Panel and under Taxonomies > Channel create your own channel in appropriate channel group.
For mobile device that should be /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Taxonomies/Channel/Online/Apps

2.
Use similar code to assign channel to interaction:

```
public async void ExampleAsync()
    {
        using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var contact = new Sitecore.XConnect.Contact();

                Guid channelId = Guid.NewGuid();
                string userAgent = "Sample User Agent";
                var interaction = new Sitecore.XConnect.Interaction(contact, InteractionInitiator.Brand, channelId, userAgent);

                Guid goalID = Guid.Parse("{21EC2020-3AEA-4069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"); // ID of goal item

                var goal = new Goal(goalID, DateTime.UtcNow);

                goal.EngagementValue = 20; // Manually setting engagement value rather than going to defintion item

                interaction.Events.Add(goal);

                client.AddContact(contact);
                client.AddInteraction(interaction);

                await client.SubmitAsync();
            }
            catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
            {
                // Handle exception
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead of `Guid channelId = Guid.NewGuid();` put there your channel item id.

Code was taken from https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/interactions/add-events.html . Take a look there for further details.

3.
You will then see the channel in Experience profile under Activity tab and Visits or Channel sections:

[image: Experience Profile showing channels]

4.
You will see also different channel type in Experience Analytics (as per your question):

[image: Experience Analytics]

Your Mobile app could be one of them :)

See more information here:

- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing_and_reporting/analytics/reporting/the_acquisition_tab_reports#_Channels
- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing_and_reporting/analytics/reporting/the_experience_analytics_reports_relevant_for_marketers